# Error at android.preference.Injector$CheckBoxPreferenceHook.after_onBindView with custom CheckBoxPreference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, checkboxpreference

I have a custom CheckBoxPreference with below code and it's not working on some devices. How do I fix it?

I have searched for some info but I cannot find the same bug.

Here is the **MCheckPreference** class code:

```
public class MCheckPreference extends CheckBoxPreference implements OnCheckedChangeListener, OnClickListener {

private TextView title;
private TextView sum;
private CheckBox toggleButton;
private LinearLayout mLinearItem;

public MCheckPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.check_preference, parent, false);
    mLinearItem = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.Item);
    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    sum = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sum);
    toggleButton = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);

    title.setText(getTitle());

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getSummary()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(getSummaryOn()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(getSummaryOff())) {
        sum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        if (isChecked()) {
            sum.setText(getSummaryOn());
        } else
            sum.setText(getSummaryOff());
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getSummaryOff()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(getSummaryOn()))
            sum.setText(getSummary());
        sum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    mLinearItem.setOnClickListener(this);
    toggleButton.setChecked(isChecked());
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, final boolean isChecked) {
    setChecked(isChecked);
    getOnPreferenceChangeListener().onPreferenceChange(this, isChecked);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    setChecked(!isChecked());
    getOnPreferenceChangeListener().onPreferenceChange(this, isChecked());
}

@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);
}
```

Here is the **LogCat**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException\
   at android.preference.Injector$CheckBoxPreferenceHook.after_onBindView(Injector.java:23)\
   at android.preference.CheckBoxPreference.onBindView(CheckBoxPreference.java:70)\
   at android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:464)\
   at android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:221)\
   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2296)\
   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)\
   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)\
   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)\
   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)\
   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2124)\
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14830)\
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4675)\
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)\
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)\
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)\
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14830)\
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4675)\
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)\
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)\
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)\
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14830)\
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4675)\
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)\
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)\
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)\
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14830)\
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4675)\
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)\
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)\
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14830)\
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4675)\
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)\
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14830)\
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4675)\
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)\
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)\
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14830)\
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4675)\
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2077)\
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1834)\
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1090)\
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5769)\
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)\
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)\
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)\
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)\
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)\
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)\
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)\
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)\
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)\
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)\
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:804)\
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)\
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why is this tagged NPE? There is no NPE...

Comment: Nvm totally missed the first line...